# Why is there garbage data coming out of my low pass func?

Tags: c++, sdl-2, lowpass-filter

Update: I added better images so you can see the issue better.

My low pass function seems to cause weird spikes every time the signal passes "ground". I've tried numerous input ranges (-1 - 1) (-127 - 128) (0 - 255). The low pass does work but there are always these spikes.

It's not a display issue either because I wrote the data to a file and opened it in audacity and it looks the same.

This is the function.
The data is loaded from a wav file and converted to 8bit mono with SDL2.
I want it to take the data from wav_buffer, apply the low pass filter, then copy it to loud_buffer. I have images below that show both displays of wav_buffer and loud_buffer.

```
    // for reference
    Uint8 *wav_buffer;
    int wav_length;
    Uint8 *loud_buffer;
    const int filter_cutoff = 2000;
    const int sRate = 44100;

    void low_pass()
    {
        float prevOutput = 0;
        float prevInput = 0;
        float x = tanf(M_PI * filter_cutoff / sRate);
        float output;
        for (int p = 0; p < wav_length; p++)
        {
            output = x * wav_buffer[p] + x * prevInput - (x-1) * prevOutput;
            output /= (x+1);
            loud_buffer[p] = output;
            prevOutput = output;
            prevInput = wav_buffer[p];
        }
    }
```

This is the data in wav_buffer. All good here.

[image]

and this is loud_buffer after the low_pass function.

[image]

Comment: I'm not good at this but if I'm interpret it correctly, you are normalizing each mini-window. Is that correct? If so, what if you don't and look at just the filter output?

Comment: I would have thought that at some stage you'd need to convert the uints to floats by subtracting 128 and vice-versa?

Comment: What are the scales on the y axes of your two graphs? Are they the same?

Comment: Does changing your first output line to the simpler (and more stable) ```output = x * wav_buffer[p] + prevOutput;``` improve anything? Also, you need to start with sensible initial values by initialising prevInput and prevOutput to wav_buffer[0], or you will be starting very close to the limit of unsigned ints.

Comment: Converting Uint8 to float via -128 gave the same result. I also tried converting to 1.0 to -1.0 and got the same thing. (1 - x) made everything peak out. And lastly output = x * input + prevOutput also made things peak out.

Comment: Your low_pass() function works OK (at least on the set of harmonics that I tried it on). The problem lies elsewhere in the code that you have not shown us.

Comment: I tried bypassing the lowpass function and it displays normally. So I'm not sure how it could be anything else.

Comment: Then I think you have to show the rest of the code. Many of your variables are global variables and you could easily overwrite them accidentally. With the made-up data that I tested it with, your filter worked OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution!
I feel kinda dumb now :|

Using Sint8 instead of Uint8 for the input and output is what fixed it.
This is clearly specific to SDL datatypes because without those types the previous function worked perfectly.

```
void low_pass()
    {
        long double x = tanf(M_PI * filter_cutoff / sRate);
        long double output = 128;
        Sint8 out; // Sint8 here was the solution :/
        Sint8 input; // ^^^
        for (int p = 0; p < wav_length; p++)
        {
            input = wav_buffer[p];
            output = x * input + x * output - (x-1) * output;
            output /= (x+1);
            out = (Sint8)output;
            loud_buffer[p] = out;
        }
    }
```

before
[image]
after
[image]